# Multiple keyword batch searching in Shiny DT tables

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyapps

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a batch keyword search in a DT datatable in R? For example, in the below code, is it possible to search for say 3 specific cars **at once** in the search box? Ideally I would like to paste in the search box at once, "Mazda RX4", "Merc 230", "Fiat 128" and then see the results in the table below without having to search each one individually.

I work in bioinformatics and colleagues of mine would like to search our interactive tables with a specific list of proteins/genes etc without having to paste each one individually.

Example code:

```r
## example taken from https://rstudio.github.io/DT/007-search.html
library(DT)
mtcars2 = mtcars[, c(1:5, 9)]
mtcars2$am = factor(mtcars$am, c(0, 1), c('automatic', 'manual'))
# search for Ma or Me
dt <- datatable(
  mtcars2, colnames = c('model' = 1),
  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
    pageLength = 5
  )
)




## simple Shiny app with datatable
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(dt)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggplot2_3.3.0        DT_0.13              rsconnect_0.8.16     shinythemes_1.1.2   
 [5] dplyr_0.8.5          shiny_1.4.0.2        BiocParallel_1.20.1  MLInterfaces_1.66.5 
 [9] cluster_2.1.0        annotate_1.64.0      XML_3.99-0.3         AnnotationDbi_1.48.0
[13] IRanges_2.20.2       MSnbase_2.12.0       ProtGenerics_1.18.0  S4Vectors_0.24.4    
[17] mzR_2.20.0           Rcpp_1.0.4.6         Biobase_2.46.0       BiocGenerics_0.32.0
```

[image: dt example]
[image: search table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for Batch Search, add a `|` pipe between the multiple car names for regex to recognise them.

```
mtcars2 = mtcars[, c(1:5, 9)]
mtcars2$am = factor(mtcars$am, c(0, 1), c('automatic', 'manual'))
# search for Ma or Me
datatable(
  mtcars2, colnames = c('model' = 1),
  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = FALSE, search = 'Maz|Hor'),
    pageLength = 5
  )
)
```

The above code will show all cars sharting with either 'Maz' or 'Hor'.

Comment: Wow, how did I not know this! Thank you!

Comment: How would you do this with user-submitted list of car names, which they paste into the Search box the OP circled in red on his image?

Comment: @EmileZäkiev have you found a solution to that?

Comment: @Nico yes Stephane Laurent is a magician here he solved it https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348919/4949259