# Batch searching regex in Shiny DT datatables with spaces (not pipes)

Tags: r, shiny, dt, shinyapps

Following on from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344987/multiple-keyword-batch-searching-in-shiny-dt-tables) can anyone please tell me if it's possible to implement a way to search an interactive Shiny DT datatable where keywords are separated by spaces and not pipes? Users of my apps will have lists of genes separated by spaces and adding pipes will defeat the point of making the app user friendly.

Example code:

```r
## example taken from https://rstudio.github.io/DT/007-search.html
library(DT)
mtcars2 = mtcars[, c(1:5, 9)]
mtcars2$am = factor(mtcars$am, c(0, 1), c('automatic', 'manual'))
dt <- datatable(
  mtcars2, colnames = c('model' = 1),
  filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
  options = list(
    search = list(regex = TRUE, caseInsensitive = TRUE),
    pageLength = 5
  )
)


## ----simple Shiny app with datatable----
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    DT::dataTableOutput("table")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(dt)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: works well]
[image: how to work]

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] ggplot2_3.3.0        DT_0.13              rsconnect_0.8.16     shinythemes_1.1.2   
 [5] dplyr_0.8.5          shiny_1.4.0.2        BiocParallel_1.20.1  MLInterfaces_1.66.5 
 [9] cluster_2.1.0        annotate_1.64.0      XML_3.99-0.3         AnnotationDbi_1.48.0
[13] IRanges_2.20.2       MSnbase_2.12.0       ProtGenerics_1.18.0  S4Vectors_0.24.4    
[17] mzR_2.20.0           Rcpp_1.0.4.6         Biobase_2.46.0       BiocGenerics_0.32.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

callback <- '
$("div.search").append($("#mySearch"));
$("#mySearch").on("keyup redraw", function(){
  var splits = $("#mySearch").val().split(" ").filter(function(x){return x !=="";})
  var searchString = "(" + splits.join("|") + ")";
  table.search(searchString, true).draw(true);
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".search {float: right;}"))),
  br(),
  tags$input(type = "text", id = "mySearch", placeholder = "Search"),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      iris[c(1,2,51,52,101,102),],
      options = list(
        dom = "l<'search'>rtip"
      ),
      callback = JS(callback)
    )
  }, server = FALSE)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks again for replying so quickly! Not sure whether to post a new question but in relation to the above post and the previous post this is linked to, if I try and incorporate both elements into my app the search box does not work. I assume this is to do the the tags? I have expanded below (happy to delete and start a new post if required). Thank you again.

Comment: @LisaBreckels Using an answer space to continue the discussion is forbidden ^^. The problem is, I think, that you have to put the stuff with `dataTableOutput` inside a `tabPanel`. A `tabsetPanel` must always be composed of `tabPanel`s.

Comment: This was indeed the problem! Thank so much and again for replying so quickly, it really is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your workarounds are always astonishing